# docker backend app not recognized in the folder

Tags: python, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to dockerize an angular application with python backend following [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dockerizing-angular-application-and-python-backend-bottle-flask-framework-21dcbf8715e5). I did all but for the docker-compose file, it says that my app.py is not present in the folder.

my python app is in 'C:\Users\Fra\Desktop\Fra\uni\Tesi\Progetto\backend'

and my angular app is in 'C:\Users\Fra\Desktop\Fra\uni\Tesi\Progetto\frontend'

i'm leaving you the dockerfiles, that should help

('Dockerfile' placed in the backend folder)

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY ./ /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto/backend/
WORKDIR /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip freeze > /requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

('Dockerfile' placed in the frontend folder)

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY /dist/macroPlan /usr/share/nginx/html
```

('docker-compose' placed in the /Progetto/ folder)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    app-backend:
        build: ./backend/
        image: app_backend
        container_name: backend
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8082:8082
    app-frontend:
        build: ./frontend/
        image: macroplan
        container_name: frontend
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 4200:4200
        expose:
            - "4200"
```

It's my first time doing something like this, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WORKDIR` is `/Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto` but your `app.py` file - which is required for container startup in `CMD` - is located in `/Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto/backend/` folder.

Rewrite your backend Dockerfile to:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY ./ /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto/backend/
WORKDIR /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto/backend/
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip freeze > /requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Or if you want to have different workdir for some reason, you have to specify correct path for your `app.py` file:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY ./ /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto/backend/
WORKDIR /Users/Fra/Desktop/Fra/uni/Tesi/Progetto
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip freeze > /requirements.txt
CMD ["python","./backend/app.py"]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
backend         |   File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
backend         |     import geopandas as gpd
backend         | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

even tho the module is installed(?)

Comment: That's the different problem. Not related to Docker and current question but to the python and your app itself. Please accept the answer and open another question if you need answers for python modules.